# How to convert datepicker format to dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my database table I use a date format which inserts dates like `04-04-2015`.
Then using a datePicker through variable `from_date` I choose the same date and that date is like `4-4-2015`. If I want to select rows using the date selected 
from datepicker I get no rows even though rows are available. How can I change the 
datePicker date to `04-04-2015` from `4-4-2015`, or insert the date like
`4-4-2015` instead of `04-04-2015`?

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(day).append("-") //day
            .append(month+1).append("-")//month
            .append(year).append(" "));//year
        from_date=dateView.getText().toString();
        startActivity(new Intent(datefrom.this, dateto.class));
    }
};
```

Code for insertion:

```
contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: "Then using a datePicker through variable from_date I choose the same date and that date is like 4-4-2015". why don't you store formatted value in from_date variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) you can achieve what you need.

```
int day=5,month=4,year=2015;
String date=String.format("%02d-%02d-%d ", day,month,year);
//output date =05-04-2015
```

Comment: Yes it is. Just for simplicity I wrote that.

Comment: @DhavalPatel The input is just three integers, and not a Date object. The output is a string. So using String.format allows us to just use those two types in a very straightforward way. The other solution introduces three intermediary classes (Calendar, SimpleFormat and Date). So it is not at all clear, whether the "better practice" argument applies here. It seems to be the question of preference and of the context.

Comment: @fdreger Sorry i misunderstood the concept. Thanks for your nice explanation. I will remove my comment.

Comment: It helped me. I had to remove the space at the end after "%d ". Then it worked.

Comment: @DhavalPatel I didn't mean to make you remove the comment, I think you have a valid point there. In many cases using SimpleDateFormat will be a much better idea (for example - it makes it much easier to handle changes in the pattern and also handles cases like 2015-04-32). It is just my knee-jerk reaction when I see a "it is always a best practice to do X" comments of posts to offset them with counter examples :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using SimpleDateFormat class. For more information visit http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.set(year, month, day);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String dateString = formatter.format(myCalendar.getTime());

        dateView.setText(dateString);
        from_date=dateString;
        startActivity(new Intent(datefrom.this, dateto.class));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getDateTime(int year, int month, int day){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    String format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(cal.getTime());
}
```