# Show date integers with 2 digits

Tags: date, datepicker, int

I want to show dates from a date picker as dd/mm/yyyy. Currently when choosing days or/and month below then 10 it gives out just von digit, e.g. 1.5.2017.
Is there any smart method give it out as 01.05.2017? Thanks!

```
 int day = DatePickerDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = DatePickerDatePicker.getMonth()+1;
 int year = DatePickerDatePicker.getYear();

 String deadline = day + "." + month + "." + year;
```

Comment: What language are u using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datepicker format to dd-MM-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731655/how-to-convert-datepicker-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy)